# Export Worksheets to Txt

Tags: excel, vba, export

I need to export multiple worksheets to .txt files. I want them to be saved in the same location as the workbook is. I also need the worksheetnames to be the .txt file names. The code below is what i have so far, but I'm getting a debugging error on sheets(ws.Name).Select....Any ideas? Thanks all!

**Also, i have this stored in my personal workbook so i can use it on any file i have open**

```
Sub Worksheets_to_txt() '<--Saves each worksheet as a text file with the same name

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim relativePath As String
    Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult

    relativePath = ThisWorkbook.Path

    answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to export worksheets?", vbYesNo, "Run Macro") '<--Pop up box to confirm export

    If answer = vbYes Then

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        Sheets(ws.Name).Select
        Sheets(ws.Name).Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        relativePath & "\" & ws.Name & ".txt", _
        FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Next
     End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why `Sheets(ws.Name).Select` rather than simply `ws.Select`? Also -- there is seldom a good reason to use `Select` in VBA, though that is a separate issue.

Comment: @JohnColeman I thought i need to select and copy the name of the sheet so i can reference it as the new .text file name?

Comment: A human needs to click to a sheet to do something with it. VBA doesn't. Your line with select does nothing at all. `ws.Copy` makes sense even if `ws` doesn't refer to the active sheet. Also -- `ws` is already a reference to a worksheet -- just use it. Refer to `ws` directly, not as "the sheet whose name is the same as the name of ws".

Answer (score 2):

If you have ***2*** or more workbooks open *(personal and another)* then replace:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
```

with

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
```

That way the `Select` will work.  *(You can't `Select` a sheet unless the proper workbook is also active)*

Also fix:

```
ThisWorkbook.Activate
```

at the bottom of the loop

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub Worksheets_to_txt() '<--Saves each worksheet as a text file with the same name

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim relativePath As String
    Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult

    relativePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

    answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to export worksheets?", vbYesNo, "Run Macro") '<--Pop up box to confirm export

    If answer = vbYes Then

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        ws.Select
        ws.Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        relativePath & "\" & ws.Name & ".txt", _
        FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        ActiveWorkbook.Activate
    Next
     End If

End Sub
```