# Export worksheets individually as .txt files from a multi-worksheet .xlsx file

Tags: excel

I have created a multi-worksheet workbook, `WKBK.xlxs`. I would like to push a button and automatically save each worksheet's cell's values only (nothing else, no formulas, etc.) separately in .txt format. Each `worksheet.txt` file would have a different assigned name. I have found the following recommended example at the end of the [this URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447139/export-worksheets-to-txt).

But when I save it as a VBS macro, exit the VBA editor, and run the macro, I get the following error:

> ActiveWorksheet.SaveAs Filename:=sheet1.txt, FileFormat:=xlText
>
> Compile error. Invalid Outside procedure.

Kindly help.

Comment: `Sheet1.txt` does not make any sense. Note that there is no such thing as a VBS macro. Also is that the only line of code you have?

Comment: Thanks for your help. A colleague solved the problem for me.